# Excel If Statement always shows false

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I can't figure out why the result is Y, even if the cell H22 has the value of 4. Shouldn't it be X ?

```
=IF(H22="4";"X";"Y")
```

Comment: try `=if(trim(h22)=4,"x","y")` to get rid of extra spaces

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanks for answering Ray. It say: We found a problem with this formula. You type: =1+1, cell shows: 2     It suggest =if(trim(h22)=4,"x","y") instead, and that gives the same result as my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=IF(H22=4,"X","Y")` with no quotes around the 4 if you want it to test for the value 4, not the string "4".

Excel will often convert between string and numeric representations but it didn't appear to in this case when I tested in Excel 2010. If I put '4 (apostrophe to force string) then your original formula returns X as you expected.

Comment: It works with the semicolon signs like this: =IF(H22=4;"X";"Y")   Thanks to your all, Mike, Rudu, and Ray

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the 4...

```
=IF(H22=4,"X","Y")
```

Excel automagically converts what it recognizes as numbers into number format, while your comparison is looking for the character 4 (not the number 4)